# Line crossing a region

Tags: c#, vector, unity-game-engine, region

I have multiple regions in 3D space and each region forms with four points. Also I have a vector and I would like to find the region that is intersected by the vector. Any help would be highly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I guess easiest way to achieve what you want is to use `BoxCollider`as `Trigger` with your regions. and do your implementation in `OnTriggerEnter()`.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, you want to find out the intersection of a ray to some 3D polygons that formed with 4 points. However, I only know how to do it with 3D boxes.

First, you need to port this to Unity, which should be very easy (source: http://tavianator.com/fast-branchless-raybounding-box-intersections/).

```
void intersection(Box b, Ray r, out float tMin, out float tMax)   
{  
    double tx1 = (b.min.x - r.x0.x)*r.n_inv.x;
    double tx2 = (b.max.x - r.x0.x)*r.n_inv.x;

    tmin = min(tx1, tx2);
    tmax = max(tx1, tx2);

    double ty1 = (b.min.y - r.x0.y)*r.n_inv.y;
    double ty2 = (b.max.y - r.x0.y)*r.n_inv.y;

    tmin = max(tmin, min(ty1, ty2));
    tmax = min(tmax, max(ty1, ty2));
}
```

Next, you need to loop through all boxes. For each loop, you can find the intersection vector by using Ray.GetPoint with tMin and tMax results.

I am quite uncertain of what you are trying to achieve, but pardon me if my answer is not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

try this instead

try shooting a ray from target to destination .

if the ray hit something it'll inform you .

refer -> http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html